# Server express over other server express

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have a server express active on port 8080 and another server express active on port 3700.
A user uses web page on "localhost:8080" to interact with the server but some functionalities are localized on server 3700. So I use a $.ajax operation inside the html/js page active on server 8080. How can i do to communicate and interact two servers? for example, If i ask "localhost:3700/getVal" inside the webpage in "localhost:8080/showVal.html" using ajax, how can i obtain the response?
This is my client code:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3700/getVal",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSONP",
            crossDomain: "true",
            data: {objectData: someObject},
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            complete: function() {
              //called when complete
              console.log('process complete');
            },

            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              console.log('process sucess');
           },

            error: function() {
              console.log('process error');
            },
          });
```

And this is server side:

```
app.get('/getVal', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.objectData);
    res.contentType('json');
    res.send({ some: JSON.stringify({response:'json'}) });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A request going to a different ports is calling a different domain under the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

You can get around this restriction by enabling [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: I used the code in this link: [link](https://gist.github.com/Zirak/3151454)
But i have this error: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. How can i resolve?